# closethick button disappear liferay popup 6.2

Tags: popup, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I am migrating the AUI popup dialog window from liferay 6.1 to liferay 6.2. I see that there are some specific changes to be made. I had some problems with display of buttons but it is resolved now. But the problem is with the close icon (x) which should be on the top right corner. It disappeared suddenly as soon as I added a save button.

Here is my code:

```
myPopup = AUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window','aui-io-deprecated', 'event', 'event-custom', function(A) {
    var buttons =[{
        cssClass: 'button_close',
        label: 'Save',
        render:true,
        id: 'myPopupButton',
        on: {
        click: function() {
            myPopupSubmit();
        }}
    }];

myPopup = Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
{
    dialog: {
        title : a + ' mytitle',
        centered : true,
        height : 600,
        width : 500,
        draggable : true,
        resizable : true,
        modal : true,
        toolbars: {
            footer:buttons
        },

    }}).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {
        uri : url
    }).render();
    myPopup.show(); 
});
}
```

Please let me know if you have any idea on it..

on `myPopupSubmit` I have also written code to close the popup as:

```
top.document.getElementById('closethick').click();
```

Since there is no `closethick` button it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [modal dialog example](http://alloyui.com/examples/modal/real-world/) as a comparison, the `X` close button is removed when using the `toolbars` property.

Reviewing [the source code](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/master/src/aui-modal/js/aui-modal.js) for the `toolbars` property (line 309 at time of writing this) indicates that if you use this property directly, you'll need to include your own `X` close in the header.

An alternative would be to use the `addToolbar` function (as seen in the example) to include your `buttons` while preserving the default toolbars.

```
modal.addToolbar([{
 cssClass: 'button_close',
 label: 'Save',
 render:true,
 id: 'myPopupButton',
 on: {
       click: function() {
         myPopupSubmit();
       }
     }
}]);
```

---

I would also consider making the instance of the dialog available to your `myPopupSubmit` function so that you would have direct access to perform `dialog.hide()` or calling `dialog.hide()` after `myPopupSubmit` versus using the `X` close approach.

If sticking with the current approach, the id being used will not work, you'll need to use a CSS selector as the YUI based id will change.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes now the X button appears but the Save button is not shown.

Comment: My mistake:i should have done myPopup.addToolbar([{...}])..It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Actually just wanted to ask if it is the right way to close a window:The X icon on top right corner works but i also want to enable closing of window after Save button is clicked. As @Origineil suggested the id will change so i need to use css selector. Can you provide one example for it. I tried other way round like: calling myPopup.hide(); after myPopupSubmit() but I get a Type error saying that myPopup.hide is not a function...may be i am doing it the wrong way..

Comment: Unless there is a need for `Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow`,  I'd render a modal dialog using the `aui-modal` approach as seen in the linked example. An example usage of your approach can be seen in [the source of the calendar portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/calendar-portlet/docroot/view_calendars.jsp). If you want to continue with your approach model it after that, on line 73 they use `.hide()`. Regarding CSS selectors, [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp) is pretty good.